# How many quirks can one have?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Through out the series so far we have seen several ways people can manifest multiple quirks. Such as Todo, which has Fire and Ice powers or Noumus power to steal quirks, allowing for multiple quirks, all though only 1 can be used at the time.

We also know that Nana had her own quirk, and still could receive One for All. Making it a case of literally 2 quirks in 1 body.

But is there a limitation known to how many quirks can be fused into 1 body/person?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The manga has an answer to this question - and it was mentioned already in the anime:

> The quirk All for One allows its holder to **steal** as many quirks as they want, as well as forcibly give those quirks to others (this is how the Nomus have been created).

---

> No limit has ever been mentioned, though having many quirks given to most people will cause a mental breakdown (explaining why Nomus act as mindless beasts).